# C++ Read file into Array / List / Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, join, vector

I am currently working on a small program to join two text files (similar to a database join). One file might look like:

```
    269ED3
    86356D
    818858
    5C8ABB
    531810
    38066C
    7485C5
    948FD4
```

The second one is similar:

```
    hsdf87347
    7485C5
    rhdff
    23487
    948FD4
```

Both files have over 1.000.000 lines and are not limited to a specific number of characters. What I would like to do is find all matching lines in both files.

I have tried a few things, Arrays, Vectors, Lists - but I am currently struggling with deciding what the best (fastest and memory easy) way.

My code currently looks like:

```
    #include iostream>
    #include fstream>
    #include string>
    #include ctime>
    #include list>
    #include algorithm>
    #include iterator>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {

        string line;

        clock_t startTime = clock();

        list data;
        //read first file
        ifstream myfile ("test.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            for(line; getline(myfile, line);/**/){
                data.push_back(line);
            }

            myfile.close();
        }

        list data2;
        //read second file
        ifstream myfile2 ("test2.txt");
        if (myfile2.is_open())
        {
            for(line; getline(myfile2, line);/**/){
                data2.push_back(line);
            }

            myfile2.close();
        }
        else cout  data2[k], k++
        //if data[j] > a;

        return 0;


    }
```

My thinking is: With a vector, random access on elements is very difficult and jumping to the next element is not optimal (not in the code, but I hope you get the point). It also takes a long time to read the file into a vector by using push_back and adding the lines one by one. With arrays the random access is easier, but reading >1.000.000 records into an array will be very memory intense and takes a long time as well. Lists can read the files faster, random access is expensive again.

Eventually I will not only look for exact matches, but also for the first 4 characters of each line.

Can you please help me deciding, what the most efficient way is? I have tried arrays, vectors and lists, but am not satisfied with the speed so far. Is there any other way to find matches, that I have not considered? I am very happy to change the code completely, looking forward to any suggestion!

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The output should list the matching values / lines. In this example the output is supposed to look like:

```
    7485C5
    948FD4
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the requirements or constraints? Do you have to report the line numbers of matching lines or just output the matching lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values for this are unique in the first file, this becomes trivial when exploiting the `O(nlogn)` characteristics of a set. The following stores all lines in the first file passed as a command-line argument to a set, then performs a `O(logn)` search for each line in the second file.

EDIT: Added 4-char-only preamble searching. To do this, the set contains only the first four chars of each line, and the search from the second looks for only the first four chars of each search-line. The second-file line is printed in its entirety if there is a match. Printing the first file full-line in entirety would be a bit more challenging.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // load set with first file
    std::ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    std::set<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;
    for (unsigned int i=1; std::getline(inf,line); ++i)
        lines.insert(line.substr(0,4));

    // load second file, identifying all entries.
    std::ifstream inf2(argv[2]);
    while (std::getline(inf2, line))
    {
        if (lines.find(line.substr(0,4)) != lines.end())
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks great, but I will have to look into that a little closer to fully understand the code. I dont even quite get where to input the file names... For the record, the files might have duplicates and they also have not exact matches, if the first 4 characters match, I want to output it as well.

Comment: Its not terribly difficult to enforce the four-char match. Just load the map with `line.substr(0,4)` instead of `line`, and in the search-loop, seach for the same; `line.substr(0,4)`. Regarding where the filenames come from, this sample takes them as command-line arguments. You would run it as `progname file1 file2`. I left the task of filename input to you, as it has nothing to do with your actual problem. Hope that makes sense. If desired, I can update the sample to do four-char leading matching as describe here, but I think it would be a good task for you.

Comment: Awesome piece of code, thanks a lot! That is really quick!! Now one last thing: I would like to match the first four characters, but would still like to output the full line. Would I be able to do something like: `while (std::getline(inf2, line.substr(0,4)))
    {
        if (lines.find(line.substr(0,4)) != lines.end())
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }`

Comment: Or did I misunderstand something here?! EDIT: Just tested my version - guess I got it wrong.

Comment: Was away for a bit. I'll update it. Its pretty simple. If this or any other answer is helpful, you should up for them, and whichever answer (this, or another) is deemed the best solution to your problem, it should be "checked". Just in case you weren't aware of this sites general operation.

Comment: Thanks, wasnt aware of that. I seem not to be able to up anything due to my very beginning of collecting points. With your suggestion, I will not be able to see the full line after it is cut down to the substring in the set - correct? If they have the first 4 characters the same, but are different, I would like to see both. And just to put some numbers behind this awesome improvement: My try was never faster than 10 seconds per 100k rows, yours takes 9 seconds for 300k.

Comment: You should still be able to print `line` from the *second* file. As I said in the comment, printing the full *first-file* line is a bit more difficult, as you would need to use a map instead of a set, and map a 4-char key of the line to its full-line value, then print that when found from the search operation. But as written above, the full second-file line should be printed if the first four chars match any first-four-chars in the first file.

Comment: Thanks again, that is great and gives me a good starting point. I might have to find a way to create my own find() function, which also might do an m to n match and not just a 1 to m. Lots to learn and explore for me!

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to create two sets and then recreate the find function based on my match type? What would be faster and require less memory? I have taken a look at the find() function for the set, but didnt understand it...

Comment: @batman No. there is no reason to create two sets that I see as of yet. The *exact*, and *complete* requirements are still not clear to me. But as the question was posed this is literally near-as-efficient as you can get. It builds an RB-tree (likely, most implementations use one for `set`, then uses that tree for O(logN) search complexity for M items, where M is the number of items in the second file. You *could* use a `std::unordered_set<>` if you wanted, which could improve your performance further. it is hash-based rather than value-based, and you would be hard-pressed to beat that.

Comment: I tried to explain my second thought in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329241/c-join-two-pipe-divided-files-on-key-fields The suggestion is a multimap, but I cant see that being efficient, but I will try this approach.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look. it would seem you need some line parsing done first to extract your keys and datum. that should be simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a 2 millions lines won't be too much slow, what might be slowing down is your comparison logic :

Use : [`std::intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

```
data1.sort(data1.begin(), data1.end()); // N1log(N1)
data2.sort(data2.begin(), data2.end()); // N2log(N2)

std::vector<int> v; //Gives the matching elements

std::set_intersection(data1.begin(), data1.end(),
                      data2.begin(), data2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(v)); 

 // Does 2(N1+N2-1) comparisons (worst case)
```

You can also try using `std::set` and insert lines into it from both files, the resultant set will have only unique elements.

Comment: You should also account for the `O(NlogN) + O(MlogM)` additional complexity required for sorting the data vectors in the overall complexity. Though likely obvious to you, it may not be to the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 2 million records is just the start - it will grow and will have to run fairly quickly. The more efficient the better.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to read the entire file at once.

Use istream::seekg and istream::tellg to figure the size of the two files. Allocate a character array large enough to store them both. Read both files into the array, at appropriate location, using istream::read.

[Here is an example of the above functions.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and report on the findings!